# How to share user location using facebook sdk? (Facebook check-in)

Tags: javascript, react-native, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to share user's current location with a placeId provided from database. It's pretty much like a check-in but since Facebook changed its Permissions rules, check-in and timeline posts are deprecated and I have to achieve this with a Share Dialog. Any suggestions?

I've already tried to send the placeId and the contentType of the share as 'opengraph', didn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can do this via a Share dialog.

Comment: I don’t think that is possible any more. The Share dialog allows users to pick a location they want to check-in to manually; but there is no way for you to specify this upfront.